# Maven plugin execution order

Tags: maven

I have problem with ordering Maven plugin executions.
I would like to execute the plugins in declaration order:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>task-1</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>task-2</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>cmd</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>/c</argument>
                        <argument>rem</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>task-3</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I expected the execution order: task-1, task-2, task-3

But after executing `mvn initialize`, the actual order is task-1, task-3, task-2:

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (task-1) @ test ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (task-3) @ test ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (task-2) @ test ---
```

What should I change to execute the plugins in the order I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that Maven warned about a duplicate plugin, i.e. maven-antrun-plugin. Maven cannot have duplicate plugins, so the result is that the executionblock of task-3 is merged into the first maven-antrun-plugin.
And now Maven will go through all plugins, top-down and look for execution blocks bound to the validate-phase.
This explains the result.
Is there an option to control the order in this case? No, not within the same phase.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, there was a "duplicate declaration of plugin" warning. Besides, this is a huge restriction in the Maven execution model...